# Sorting a string of numbers received via query string

Tags: javascript

For my application I am passing in a string of numbers via query string and would like to find the median of all the numbers. This task is pretty simple when working with actual numbers, but considering that I am trying to find the median of a string of numbers, I must convert the string into an array, sort it, convert the nums to integers etc. How could I achieve this result? Here is how I tried to achieve this:

```
 let nums = req.query
 let numArr = undefined

    for(let x in nums) {
        strX = nums[x].replace(/,/g, '').split('').sort();
        numArr = strX.map(x => parseInt(x))
    }
```

This method does not work for examples such as `'5,7,9,1,12'` because it sorts the array like this `[1,1,2,5,7,9]`

Comment: 1. Is `req.query` a string of numbers (e.g. `5,7,9,1,12`)?

2. You are overwriting `numArr` for every number, which doesn't seem like what you want to do. Are you intending for `numArr` to be the string of numbers converted into integers?

Comment: When you replace the commas, the result is '579112'. When you split this by '', the result is '5,7,9,1,1,2'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default behavior of Array.sort is to compare item as UTF16 strings. But you can override that behavior by using your compare function.

`'5,7,9,1,12'.split(',').map(n => parseInt(n, 10)).sort((a,b) => a - b)`

Comment: Why `n => parseInt(n, 10)` instead of `Number` or even just `n=>+n`?

Comment: OK as long as the array doesn't contain Infinity or NaN.

Comment: Cause +n is a trick. parseInt is explicit.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a the string as part of a JSON string and get an array of numbers, sort it and get the median value, depending of the length of the array.

```js
const
    string = '5,7,9,1,12',
    array = JSON
        .parse(`[${string}]`)
        .sort((a, b) => a - b),
    median = array.length % 2
        ? array[array.length >> 1]
        : (array[(array.length >> 1) - 1] + array[array.length >> 1]) / 2;

console.log(...array);
console.log(median);
```

Comment: What if string contains duplicate numbers?

Comment: @GirkovArpa, it does not matter for getting a media, if a number occures more then one time.

Comment: The custom sorting comparator function is redundant as the default behaviour for `sort()` on numbers is to sort them in ascending order.

Comment: @AnsonMiu, no, because the [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) without callback sorts strings, so you get 11 < 2 and this is not wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

```js
 let nums = req.query
 let numArr = undefined

 for(let x in nums) {
     strX = nums[x].split(',').map(x => parseInt(x)).sort((x,y) => x - y);
 }
```

However I think the loop is redundant, though I haven't tested it.
That is, you can do

```js
 let nums = req.query
 let numArr = nums.split(",").map(x => parseInt(x)).sort((x,y) => x - y);
```

Comment: Should do `.sort()` _after_ `.map()`, because `["1", "2", "12"]` will be sorted as `["1", "12", "2"]` in their string representations, as supposed to `[1, 2, 12]` in their numerical forms.

Comment: +as per the comment from @Nina Scholz , the `sort()` function will sort by string lexicographical order, so a custom comparator `.sort((x, y) => x - y)` is needed